# No enum constant org.primefaces.extensions.component.exporter.DefaultExporterFactory.ExporterType.CSV

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, export, primefaces-extensions

I'm using PrimeFaces Extension to export data using its data table's `rowExpansion`, because native PrimeFaces doesn't support this kind of structure. I don't want to write pure iText code for the sake of practicality.

HTML:

```
<p:commandLink id="csv" ajax="false">
    <h:outputText value="CSV" />

    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="false" target="#{panoramicaMB.customExporter}" />

    <pe:exporter type="csv"
                 target="tabela"
                 fileName="panoramicas"
                 facetBackground="#AAFFBB"  
                 datasetPadding="4" />
 </p:commandLink>
```

The attribute `customExporter` is a primitive boolean. I changed from `isCustomExporter()` to `getCustomExporter()`. Same result with both names.

Partial stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.primefaces.extensions.component.exporter.DefaultExporterFactory.ExporterType.CSV
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
at org.primefaces.extensions.component.exporter.DefaultExporterFactory$ExporterType.valueOf(ExporterFactoryProvider.java:57)
at org.primefaces.extensions.component.exporter.DefaultExporterFactory.getExporterForType(ExporterFactoryProvider.java:67)
at org.primefaces.extensions.component.exporter.DataExporter.processAction(DataExporter.java:174)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
at br.com.shelfpix.filters.FiltroDeConexao.doFilter(FiltroDeConexao.java:230)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56)
at ...
```

Comment: Which version of primefaces extensions are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the PrimeFaces Extensions' documentation:

`type   Export type: "pdf","xlsx".`

It does not seem like CSV is supported.

Comment: You're right. :/ I thought it supported all PrimeFaces formats. Thanks!